# Laravel helper method for active the sidebar

Tags: html, css, laravel

I am trying to use the laravel helper method for active the sidebar but it does not working. Can anyone tell us how to apply Laravel helper method to this sidebar.
Here this is my sidebar.blade.php file

```
<aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary">
    <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
    <!-- Brand Logo -->
    <a href="{{url('dashboard')}}" class="brand-link">
        <img src="{{asset('assets/adminlte-boot-4/dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png')}}" alt="Digital CRM" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3"
             style="opacity: .8">
        <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">DIgital CRM</span>
    </a>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar-menu">
        <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->


        <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
        <nav class="mt-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
                <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
                     with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="{{url('dashboard')}}" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                        <p>Dashboard</p>
                    </a>
                </li>


                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="{{url('webtolead')}}" class="nav-link">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-file"></i>
                        <p>Web to Lead</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
               </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
</aside>
```

Comment: what helper method?

Comment: @lagbox laravel active sidebar helper method

Comment: there is no such thing

Comment: @lagbox visit this, you will understand: [link](https://quickadminpanel.com/blog/laravel-how-to-make-menu-item-active-by-urlroute/)

Comment: i know what you want to do, i was saying there is no such helper that actually does it for you

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this: add these method in your tag:

```
<li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="{{url('accounts')}}" class="nav-link {{ request()->is('accounts*') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-user"></i>
                        <p>Accounts</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

OR

```
<li class="nav-item ">
            <a href="{{url('admin/updateprofile')}}" class="nav-link {{ Request::is('*admin/updateprofile*')? 'active' : '' }}">
              <i class="fas fa-user nav-icon"></i>
              <p>ProfileEdit</p>
            </a>
          </li>
```

both method are working...
Creating helper.php is good but this method is short in my case.

```
<aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary">
    <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
    <!-- Brand Logo -->
    <a href="{{url('dashboard')}}" class="brand-link">
        <img src="{{asset('assets/adminlte-boot-4/dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png')}}" alt="Digital CRM" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3"
             style="opacity: .8">
        <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">DIgital CRM</span>
    </a>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar-menu">
        <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->


        <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
        <nav class="mt-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
                <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
                     with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="{{url('dashboard')}}" class="nav-link {{ request()->is('dashboard') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                        <p>Dashboard</p>
                    </a>
                </li>


                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="{{url('webtolead')}}" class="nav-link {{ request()->is('webtolead*') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-file"></i>
                        <p>Web to Lead</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
               </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
</aside>
```